# collect() function in PySpark taking excessively long time to complete

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am looking for suggestions to optimize the code below. Currently this code is taking about 25 minutes to complete on an EMR cluster with 2 worker nodes.

```
wall_start_time = time.time()

## Experimenting with bringing all data onto the master node
uid_vector_df = document_vector_df.select('uid', 'Glove Document Vector')

print("#Rows = %d" % uid_vector_df.count())
print("#Columns = %d" % len(uid_vector_df.columns))
print("#Num Partitions = %d" % uid_vector_df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
print("Schema")
uid_vector_df.printSchema()

projected_data_on_master = uid_vector_df.collect()

total_wall_time = time.time() - wall_start_time
print("Wall Time taken (in secs) to collect data on master node = {}".format(total_wall_time))
```

Here is the output of the print statements

```
#Rows = 2000
#Columns = 2
#Num Partitions = 1
Schema
root
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Glove Document Vector: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
```

This code is taking an excessively long time. I have tried running it on the local PySpark setup and running it on EMR as well. Below is the nature of data.

Each row is comprised of a string (uid) and a Vector of floats. The size of each vector is 300. That means each row is about 64 (bytes) + 300 * 8 (bytes) , assuming float is 8 bytes That means for 2000 rows, the size of the data is less than 5MB

I am really surprised as to why such a tiny amount of data is taking so long to get collected in the master node. Please let me know how I can optimize this simple piece of code.

Thanks

P.S. I know that the collect() operation is frowned upon, but there is a legitimate use case where we would like to collect data on the master node to perform batch clustering using FAISS. So I am not looking for suggestions on how to avoid the collect() operation altogether

Comment: Why do you want to collect the data ?

Comment: Included the reason in the question above as post script.